# Last save point in Lufia II: Rise of the Sinistrals

Tags: lufia-2

I was wondering where the last save point in Lufia II: Rise of the Sinistrals (SNES) was, what the latest point is you can can go back there to save your progress, and whether you can return to the overworld again (In games like Golden Sun you're stuck in the final town if you save just before the final credits).

Comment: oh man, I've probably spent more time dungeon diving in that game than I have spent playing other games in its entirety.  Gotta find those blue and red chests!

Comment: this is only from memory (at least 10+ years ago), but I think as long as you save before entering the last fortress you can still explore the world.

Comment: I think @yx. is correct but it's been so long for me as well that I really don't remember.  I'm tempted to blitz through a playthrough and find out but even in a hurry it'd be 30+ hours, probably...

Answer (score 1):

From looking through the [walkthroughs](http://forfeit.electromaz.com/lufia2/walkthrough/), the point of no return is the completion of the Kamirno Island tower.  After that point you will be unable to explore the world map and have to finish the game.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean you can still Escape the tower just before the forced story sequence takes over?  I believe you can move freely AFTER the last battles so that's why I'm wondering, since that way you get to keep the XP and money from the final fights and are still able to get back to the overworld.  Can someone confirm this?

Comment: #HSO yes, you can enter the tower and leave but once you go beyond the save point after Leach you are stuck.